# How to upload file to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a upload.php which uploads only PDF, DOC and DOCX to the database (path) and a file on my server. Now my upload to the file is working but I do not really know how to upload the link(path) to my table row.

Also the file I am uploading has to be able to be download by a click on a button on a detail page.

My upload.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 if ($_FILES["cv"]["error"] > 0)
{
 echo "<font size = '5'><font color=\"#e31919\">Error: NO CHOSEN FILE <br />";
 echo"<p><font size = '5'><font color=\"#e31919\">INSERT TO DATABASE FAILED";
}
else
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"],"files/" . $_FILES["cv"]["name"]);
 echo"<font size = '5'><font color=\"#0CF44A\">SAVED<br>";

 $file="files/".$_FILES["cv"]["name"];
 $sql="INSERT INTO person (person_cv, path) VALUES ('','$file')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql))
 {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 echo "<font size = '5'><font color=\"#0CF44A\">SAVED TO DATABASE";

}

mysql_close();

?>
```

The database name is called "persons" which has a table called person. The file link should save to person_cv. I am new to PHP and I am trying to understand PHP however there are so many ways to do it because of that I am getting confused.

Comment: Are you getting any errors with this code?

Comment: I don't because the code is working and it does upload the file to a directory on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused of database structure too, as I see.

I don't know what data you really want to keep in database, but you need following:

- table with basic data (called for example `people_id`), where you will have for example

  - `id`
  - `name` and `surname`
  - `cv_file_id`
- table with file info

  - `file_id` (values must be the same as in `cv_file_id`)
  - `name` (may be exact name of file as was before uploading, or rather changed for better manipulation)
  - `type` (dfefined mostly by extension, like doc, docx, txt or so)
- and probably also some other tables for informations of people, themselves

And in domain folders you will have one, where you will keep all uploaded cv files. And then, you will update db tables as needed - and also upload those files.

That is the most reasonable way how to do it. I would do it in this way. May it be that someone more experienced would do it in else way.

Comment: So if I am right, I have to create an other table where file_id has a relation with cv_file_id or in my case person_cv. I am not really using this for a long term maybe just for 1 week. So if there is way without using/creating other tables and just use my person_cv that would be great. And yes I do have two tables called person and address where address is linked to person.